# Add Attributes to ActionText / Trix Attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trix, actiontext

When adding an attachment to my editor I want to add attributes.  The core editor does something similar with Image attachments where you can add Captions.

How can I add the attributes? How Can I access them when rendering the attachment in the partial?

So I want to do something like this:

```
const attachment = new Trix.Attachment({content, sgid})
  attachment.setAttributes('link_text': 'some text', 'link_class': 'a-class')
  this.element.editor.insertAttachment(attachment)
```

And then in the partial gain access to those attrributes.